# Updating "Number" widgets with mysql query data - Dashing

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems

I am very much new to ruby and I am trying to set up a test dashboard. I see that mysql gives the total count of the sql query. However its not getting populated on the widget.Can someone please help?

```
# mysql.rb (jobs file)    
require "mysql2"

SCHEDULER.every '5s' do
  client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "192.168.1.3",:username => "testuser",:database => 'testdb')

  results=client.query("SELECT count(*) as total from testdb.share")
  puts results

  results.each do |row|
    puts row['total']
    send_event('totals', { value: total })
  end
end
```

The dashboard file:

```
# sample.erb
<li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
  <div data-id="totals" data-view="Number" data-title="Number of Shares" data-moreinfo="Shares" data-prefix="$"></div>
</li>
....
```

Dashing console shows as below

```
#<Mysql2::Result:0x007f98b4b85d18> 
3   --->>>> This is the count of my mysql query
```

Scheduler caught exception:

```
> undefined local variable or method `total' for main:Object
> /home/user/.rvm/sweet_dashboard_project/jobs/mysql.rb:20:in `block (2
> levels) in <top (required)>'
> /home/user/.rvm/sweet_dashboard_project/jobs/mysql.rb:11:in `each'
> /home/user/.rvm/sweet_dashboard_project/jobs/mysql.rb:11:in `block in
> <top (required)>'
> /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.24/lib/rufus/sc/jobs.rb:230:in
> `call'
> /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.24/lib/rufus/sc/jobs.rb:230:in
> `trigger_block'
> /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.24/lib/rufus/sc/jobs.rb:204:in
> `block in trigger'
> /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.24/lib/rufus/sc/scheduler.rb:430:in
> `call'
> /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.24/lib/rufus/sc/scheduler.rb:430:in
> `block in trigger_job'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
results.each do |row|
  puts row['total']
  send_event('totals', { value: total })
end
```

Check the line `send_event('totals', { value: total })`. You are setting `value` to `total`, but you haven't set that variable or method (i.e. `total`) anywhere, thus the `undefined local variable or method` error.

It think that you want to assign `row['total']` instead:

```
results.each do |row|
  puts row['total']
  send_event('totals', { value: row['total'] })
end
```

**UPDATE**

To show the values in the widget, you must use `current` instead of `value` to get the correct binding (in `send_event()`) , so the above code becomes:

```
results.each do |row|
  puts row['total']
  send_event('totals', { current: row['total'] })
end
```

An alternative is to change `current` to `value` in the source file `widgets/number/number.html`.

So this line:

```
<h2 class="value" data-bind="current | shortenedNumber | prepend prefix | append suffix"></h2>
```

would become:

```
<h2 class="value" data-bind="value | shortenedNumber | prepend prefix | append suffix"></h2>
```

Although i won't recommend this, its better to keep the defaults (that is, `current`).

Comment: Thanks Gerry. Your code modification helped but still widget is not updated.
....................                 
results.each do |row| 
  puts row['total']
  send_event('totals', { value: row['total'] })
end 
                                                          
 Job shows the count(variable total) value as "3" . Somehow this value is not getting sent to widget  " totals"
<li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
 <div data-id="totals" data-view="Number" data-title="Number of Shares" data-moreinfo="Shares" data-prefix=""></div>  . Please advise.

Comment: @Mike Got it, you must use `current` binding instead of `value`, so change `send_event('totals', { value: row['total'] })` to `send_event('totals', { current: row['total'] })`; check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks alot Gerry. It worked perfectly. Can you please let me know if there is any documentation to understand this workflow?

Comment: @Mike go to `sweet_dashboard_project/widgets` and you will find a directory with source files for each `data-view`. Open the `.html` file, which contains the source html of the widget and look for any `data-bind` value, those are the ones you could use in `send_event()`. You can change that file to customize your widget as well.

Comment: @Mike You can check their [homepage](http://dashing.io/), i know, is kind of basic; but use that information while browsing the `widget` directory and you will get a better understanding of how this gem works.

Comment: Thank you so much,Gerry.You helped me alot